# Changing date format using FORMAT

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-format

I've got dates in my database stored as varchars in the format: dd/mm/yyyy e.g. 1/3/2015

I'm trying to change the format to yyyy/mm/dd so I can convert them into timestamps.

When I try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT (date, 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'yyyy/mm/dd' ) AS t FROM tracker;
```

It returns only one number per record which happens to be the day. So if I run the query on the following dates: 2/3/2015 and 6/2/2014 then the query returns 2 and 6.

How can I get it to return the correct format?

Comment: `FORMAT` is for numbers. Did you mean to use `DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: Apparently it can be used for dates: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx  ..... I tried SELECT DATE_FORMAT (date,  'yyyy/mm/dd' ) AS t FROM tracker; but it just returns NULL for all

Comment: @flodorhlod, the link you posted is specific to Microsoft SQL Server, but the question is tagged MySQL. Both are similar products, but differ slightly in their SQL syntax and functionality.

Comment: please also post the result you get from the queries `SELECT date FROM tracker LIMIT 10` & `DESCRIBE tracker`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using the wrong MySQL functions here. You're looking for [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) which will convert that date string into a date value which MySQL can work with. You can then use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert it to a new date string of your choosing.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y/%m/%d') AS t FROM tracker;
```

Answer (score 1):

To output `datetime` & `timestamps` in specific formats, you can use the [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

It works like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_date_field, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') FROM my_table
```

Incidentally, specifying the format as `'%Y/%m/%d'` will render your date field as 1999/12/31.

To output the datetime value in a timestamp use the function [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

Comment: Does this work if the date is not in a standard format? Isn't `'dd/mm/yyyy'` ambiguous?

Comment: you're right, the varchar has to be converted to a date first, then rendering can happen via the date_format function.